# UV Mapping External Texture Changes to a Black Diffuse in Texture Paint mode

Tags: texturing, uv

Okay, so I've seen the other answers to this here in Blender Exchange. However, as far as I can figure out those textures were not saved when created in texture paint mode.

I added an **external** texture to my object:

[image: 1]

...then I switched to texture paint mode and the texture changes to a complete black texture:

[image: 2]

However if I switch back the texture while in texture paint mode it still keeps my object black:

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Is this a lighting problem? Or am I not importing the external image correctly? I have tried packing/saving the image after importing it and putting it on my UV Map and then switching to texture paint mode, but it still occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the painting mode to *Image* and selecting your image in *3D view > tool shelf > Slots* while in texture paint mode:

[image]