# Texture Painting, problem with bump painting

Tags: texture-painting

Whenever i am painting bump maps, it paints on the color map. I read on one of the other thread and made sure of these five things.
[image]

Even though, I have the bump map selected in image editor, when i paint in texture paint mode, it still paints on the color map. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles? Note that the texture painting system changed a bit recently. Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17948/599

Comment: I am using BI at the moment.